# Typescript Inheritance in Interfaces

Tags: typescript, inheritance, interface

First time using typescript, and would like to know how to best deal with this situation.

I have some json data coming from API, say

```
{"name" : "A Person", "age": "25", createdAt: "timestamp"}
```

And I have an interface IPersonData which represents the incoming JSON.

```
export interface IPersonData {
  name: string;
  createdAt: string;
  age: string;
}
```

But then an actual Person Object within in the system:

```
export interface IPerson extends IPersonData {
  createdAt: DateTime; //this is the luxon DateTime
  age: number;
}
```

Webstorm does not yell at me (and actually provides an icon saying its overridden) but the compiler hates it, letting me know
`Type 'DateTime' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

I have tried this too,

```
 export interface IPerson extends Omit<IPersonData, "createdAt">{
  createdAt: DateTime; //this is the luxon DateTime
  age: number;
}
```

Can I override in typescript, and if not, is there value in representing the JSON coming into the system, (We use the same types to validate the JSON leaving the API).

Comment: “I have tried this too”... and what happened?  What doesn’t work about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there with your final snippet. You probably got this error:

```
Interface 'IPerson' incorrectly extends interface 'Omit<IPersonData, "createdAt">'.
  Types of property 'age' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2430)
```

What is important to note is that it's *not* complaining about `createdAt`. So its working for that field. And since you are changing `age` to a `number` from a `string`, you need to omit that one too.

One thing you may not know, is that you can omit many fields with `Omit` by passing in a union of strings.

```
export interface IPerson extends Omit<IPersonData, 'createdAt' | 'age'> {
  createdAt: DateTime;
  age: number;
}
```

Which does what you expect.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEQIYwKYBVQbgXzgDMoIQ4ByAGwFcAPCAOwoCgWM7JY5hHMoiqAMZ4AkgAUMUAM5M0MVIhZw4jVCAwAuONJhReAcwDcyuEKgZ0GACYBBGNt37Gx06gNadewyfxsOXPC8-IIicBJSsoxwHJiM1tJwAPIgwDAAPBEycuioADSU5paYdjAUcAA+lO4YFAB8SipFVqXa8ti4RnAA9N0wABbAiUNwA3i0DNHtOBpuHtqMNCAARlK+QA)

Comment: Thank you.  This was a simplified version, but that playground you built allowed me to experiment and find the solution.  Thanks again.